# How do I annotate a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I want to write a function to get some data in a HashMap, only that its value can be a HashMap.

So, my data would look something like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  }
}
```

And I'm looking for an annotation like `HashMap<String, HashMap<...>`

How can i annotate this in my function?

Comment: You mean `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`?

Comment: You might want some offspring of serde crate, to use a well-tested recursive serialization/deserialization. E.g. `serde_json`

Comment: *"can be"* - Those are tho most critical words to me in your question. Rust is typesafe, so do you mean, are definitely a HashMap? Or might be a HashMap or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume with *"can be a HashMap"* you mean *"is definitely a HashMap"*? Because in Rust, you have to know all the types at compile time, so a "maybe" isn't quite that easy.

Assuming you mean *"is definitely"*, this works:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut x: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> = HashMap::new();

    let foo_entry = x.entry("foo".to_string()).or_insert_with(HashMap::new);
    foo_entry.insert("bar".to_string(), "baz".to_string());

    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "baz",
    },
}
```

---

If you mean "might be" then I assume that you have a `JSON`- like situation, for which I can wholeheartedly recommend the [`serde-json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) library:

```
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let x = json!({
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    });

    println!("As Debug: \n{:#?}\n", x);
    println!("As JSON serialized: \n{}", x.to_string());
}
```

```
As Debug: 
Object({
    "foo": Object({
        "bar": String(
            "baz",
        ),
    }),
})

As JSON serialized: 
{"foo":{"bar":"baz"}}
```